# Can I use one form for add and edit List Items?

Tags: sharepoint

I created custom edit form and custom add form for my List. Both forms have the same FormFields and they differ only by ControlMode tag. In add form ControlMode="New" and in edit form: ControlMoe="Edit".
When I try use edit form as NewForm, in all input box I see text "... field value" insted of empty box. And when I try use add form as EditForm, all input boxes are empty insted of field value.
Can I somehow use one aspx file as newForm and EditForm at the same time to not duplicate aspx files?

Answer (score 1):

**For sharepoint webpart page(site page):** No you can not have same form for both
**For Sharepoint application page:** yes you can. you have almost complete control over you application page.

**For more info about difference in site page and application page:**
http://akifkamalsyed.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/sharepoint-application-pages-vs-site-pages/
http://jwalin.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/difference-between-site-pages-and-application-pages/

Comment: In application page I should set ControlMode value in Page_Load ? And how to detect mode in Page_Load (New or Edit)?